# How a deployed WCF service in Windows Azure with "Connected" Point-to-Site VPN can Communicate/Access a local Intranet?

Tags: wcf, azure, vpn, intranet

My client has a public-facing Internet website, and a local Intranet. However, The two sites are completely separated.

My client requested us to implement a specific functionality (WCF Service), and this service is actually supposed to communicate with both sites: their Internet and their Intranet, and perform some operations.

We have created the functionality (The WCF Service) and deployed it in Windows Azure, and its URL is: (http://OurService.cloudapp.net/OurService.svc). So, We, deployed the WCF service as a windows azure cloud service,

The functionality (The WCF Service) is working perfectly with their Internet website, simply because all the URLs are public and accessible.

However, I am unable to connect our Azure WCF Service with the client's local Intranet.

I have learnt about Windows Azure Virtual Network, and in theory it is supposed to be the solution for my case because it is supposed to securely connect my cloud infrastructure to my on-premise datacenter and the build cloud application hosted in a hybrid environment.

I have successfully created and configured correctly a Point-to-Site VPN, and YES, The "Connected" icon is showing up in the network area of my machine.

Nevertheless, Even though that the Point-to-Site VPN is "Connected", But, Everytime our Azure WCF Service tries accessing any local site's URL e.g. (http://intranet.ABC123.com/), I get the *error message*: "**The remote name could not be resolved**".

**Any idea how to fix this issue ?**

**Therefore, Could you please help me out and tell me how can I make my WCF Service which is currently deployed in Windows Azure in the cloud communicate (Access and perform operation) in the local Intranet ?**

I would greatly appreciate your inputs !

**PS:** Please, Let's skip the Service Bus option, Because It will NOT be considered at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you configure Azure Virtual Network, you are responsible for name resolution. The first stop of one working with Azure Infrastructure Services (Virtual Machines / Virtual Network / Cloud Services) is the very important to read article: [Name Resolution in Windows Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156088.aspx).

However when working with PTS (Point-To-Site) VPN, you are aware that **as of today** it is CTP. Thus you practically cannot get out-of-the box easy solution to resolve `local` machines from the cloud when using PTS VPN. This is not the case with STS (Site-To-Site) VPN. Simply because PTS VPN assigns IP Address randomly to the connected machines, while with STS VPN you are in control of all the IP Addresses assigned to your local network. Also note, that STS VPN can be established using Windows Server 2012 as a VPN gateway for the local (corporate) network. For a corporate solution I would never advise using PTS. PTS is just for information worker machines, not for connecting servers.